# Layout: Make the textarea (edit box) for answers and the preview reflect the final width even before posting

Tags: feature-request, design

Before an answer being composed is posted, the textarea element (edit box) is *wider* than the answer that will render once actually posted, because the width that is later taken up by the vote tally (balance of votes) is initially available for editing as well.

(The problem goes away when you subsequently *edit* an answer.)

Can we make the **textarea *and preview***<sup>[11]</sup> reflect the actual rendering width up front, even before an answer is posted?

Avoiding the need for horizontal scrolling of code is an important aspect of making it readable.

Not knowing the true width ahead of time makes it hard to gauge whether scrolling will be avoided or not.
This is problematic with long code lines as typically found in *shell* programming, notably in long PowerShell pipelines.

**Note**:

- **The *preview* is *also* based on the extra width, which is the crux of the problem - you truly won't know whether your code blocks will scroll horizontally until you *post*.**
- As @Makyen points out in the comments, **fixing the preview width is not a *perfect, universal* solution**, due to rendering differences across platforms, browsers, and screen sizes. However, **there is *some* consistency to be had**, even at resolutions as low as 1280 x 800, and **even the variations amount to much smaller errors than the incorrect initial preview** - see bottom.

[image: width problem]

---

#### Rendering differences across platforms and browsers:

Screen shots from a 1280 x 800 laptop screen, in a maximized browser window, with default settings (note that the post width only shrinks if you make your window too narrow to accommodate all elements; conversely going beyond that width does *not* make the posts wider):

**Conclusions:**

- Cross-platform:

  - No single browser renders the same across all platforms.
  - Firefox on Ubuntu renders with the fewest visible characters.
- macOS: All browsers render the same.
- Windows: All browsers show *more* than on macOS, with only Edge, Chrome / Opera rendering the same, Firefox showing the most, IE 11 the least (but still more than on macOS; it is the only browser rendering a lower *absolute* width across all browsers and platforms).
- Ubuntu: Chrome / Opera render the same as on macOS, but not Windows. Firefox renders differently, with the fewest number of characters visible overall.

**Your browser:**

```bsh
$ScriptBlock = {
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\*\My -Recurse |
    Select Subject,DnsNameList,NotAfter,NotBefore,Thumbprint,Issuer,
           @{n="SAN";e={Try {($_.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.Value -eq '2.5.29.17'}).Format(0)} Catch{} }},
```

**macOS 10.14.1**:

Chrome 70.0.3538.102 and Opera 56.0:

[image]

Safari 12.0.1:

[image]

Firefox 63.0.3:

[image]

**Microsoft Windows 10** Pro (64-bit; Version 1803, OS Build: 17134.407)

Edge:

[image]

Chrome 70.0.3538.102 and Opera 56.0.3051.104:

[image]

Firefox 63.0.3:

[image]

IE 11:

[image]

**Ubuntu 18.04.1**:

Firefox 63.0:

[image]

Chrome 70.0.3538.110-1 and Opera 56.0.3051.104:

[image]

---

<sup>[11] What ultimately matters is whether the *preview* is faithful in terms of rendering width; while the textarea could remain wider, having it differ in width from the associated preview could be confusing / esthetically displeasing, however - I have no strong feelings either way.</sup>

Comment: That's what the code preview is for.

Comment: @publicstaticvoidmain: No, it isn't, because the preview _also_ shows the extra width - in other words: it is not a preview of what will actually render. I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Now I see what you mean

Comment: Your code should render the same regardless if it is properly formatted as code.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Not with respect to the actual _width_ once posted. That is, the preview may suggest that there'll be _no horizontal scrolling_, yet on posting there may be - that's the concern; in practice it is a frequent problem with _shell_ command lines; I've added that note to the answer.

Comment: Note that the final width of the text will likely not match the width of the textarea because of font differences, markdown, etc. The _preview_ would be better served if it was the same width as the final output though, so I agree with that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Yes, what ultimately matters is the preview, and I've made that clearer in the question. I guess the textarea could remain wider, but having it differ in width from the associated preview might be confusing.

Comment: While this is possible, you have to take into account that the number of characters wide for code blocks is different in each browser. Assuming that's not resolved by SE, then the only solution is to have the width of the edit textarea be that which results in the text wrapping with the minimum number of characters in any browser. Note: the width you need set is different in each browser to obtain this same number of minimum characters. Also note that it's not a matter of the edit text area just having the same width in characters, as you must account for the 4 spaces in front of code lines.

Comment: This, of course, also doesn't take into account that SE's post display area is semi-responsive, so the user may have their display/window set such that the width of the post's code block is significantly smaller than the maximum which SE permits.

Comment: So, in other words, even if you are writing your code such that it doesn't wrap for you, that does not mean that it won't wrap for someone else using a different browser/OS, or the same browser, but with just a window size smaller than the default. The differences, even using the default maximum sizes, are a couple/few characters horizontally and a couple/few lines vertically. Note: I mean H and/or V scrolling after posting, as there are differences between what is previewed, both horizontally and vertically both before and after initial posting and before and after reloading the page.

Comment: @Makyen you may want to post it as an answer taking the counter-part of this FR? I for one whose screen size always change, almost never see twice a post with the same layout. So the fact that it was rendered the same when I posted it as what I had in the editor is one of the last things I'd like SE devs to spend on, since anyway when I'll get back to it, it won't be the same anymore.

Comment: It's worth noting that the width is screen and window dependent anyway, meaning the width you see isn't necessarily what everyone else sees.

Comment: @Makyen: Good points, so the answer is: it's not a perfect, universal solution, but there's enough consistency to make the fix worthwhile - I've updated the answer with screen shots of rendering differences across platforms and browsers.

Comment: @jpmc26: Yes, but please see my update about rendering differences and the consistence that _can_ be had, within limits.

Comment: @Kaiido: The purpose of a preview is to show you how things will render, which is currently broken. The fact that rendering may be different in different situation doesn't mean that a _best - and simple - effort_ should be made to show you how things will render. As my update shows, there _is_ rendering consistency to be had, albeit not universally.

Comment: @mklement0 I disagree about it being "broken". Its role is to show how the **markup** gets transformed as html rendered by the browser. This works. Once again, size consistency means nothing since no two people should have the same browser's window width. Not losing the 60px of the vote panel, nor the time of devs is a win. I think you miss something. In your question, you speak about the *true width*, but because of responsive design that got included lately, there is no such *true width* anymore.

Comment: @Kaiido: As an ideal to approximate it _does_ mean something, and within the constraints laid out in the question, it would. There is no _win_ with the current behavior, only _misdirection_.

Comment: @mklement0 I'd argie the only misdirection here has been to make you think that what you see is what the other ones will see...

Comment: @Kaiido: I'm all ears if you have specific objections to the points made it in my question. Otherwise, I'm not interested in further engaging the you-can't-know-how-it-renders-ever-so-why-not-give-up line of reasoning.

Comment: Great idea! I have been wondering for *years* why my code preview is slightly wrong. If this idea gets implemented, it will save much head-scratching for people like me.